# Paint red lines on rulers indicating the mouse position (MFC/Direct2D)

Tags: graphics, mfc, directx, direct2d

I would like to implement red lines moving oh H/V rulers similar to what I see in windows paint brush (8.1) indicating current mouse position. See the example (red line at 560):

[image: example]

What would be the best way to do it. Direct2D Animation? layers? any other simple trick? The thing here is of cause doing it efficiently without repainting the whole area on mouse move.

I currently using MFC/direct2d so I paint myself the area with field and rulers inside the view, so I have full control on graphics here.

Comment: Whenever the mouse moves, simply [invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f3csed3.aspx) the rectangle where you previously rendered your marker.

Comment: Also 1. How would I return what was before marker there? Should I repaint everything or each time remember what was before ? How along with the repaint message I pass to onDraw2d why this message occured (MouseHover) so it would know that it should move marker instead of repainting it?

Comment: You don't have to remember anything. You simply invalidate the appropriate portion of the window, and during then next render pass (when the application receives a `WM_PAiNT` message), the contents are rendered. This restores the previous content.

Comment: I have attached the picture above, so t would be easier to discuss. Suppose I drew the picture (the rulers and the grid) as it appears above. Now the mouse has moved from 560 X coordinate I need 1) erase the previous line - pay attention that I have to remember what was before the line was drawn so I can restore the ruler picture correctly  2) Draw red line on new mouse position.

Comment: How you are drawing the picture ? Direct2D or just GDI ?

Comment: I am drawing Direct2D

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to attack this problem. The simplest is to rely on your `OnPaint` function to paint the line in a location based on a member variable. In your `OnMouseMove` handler, call `InvalidateRect` on the current location of the line based on the saved variable, update the variable, and call `InvalidateRect` a second time for the new line position.

The `BeginPaint` call that is generated in the `CPaintDC` constructor will set a clipping region based on the invalidation rectangles you provided. Even if your `OnPaint` tries to paint the entire window, only those parts that have been invalidated will be redrawn. If this is too inefficient, you can cache the ruler in a bitmap and use `GetClipBox` to determine which part of the bitmap to blit to the screen.

Comment: I currently ended up with just redrawing the whole picture upon mouse move which seems to me criminally ineffective. The thing is that I got confused with graphics repaint optimization, e.g in repaint I should figure out not only that mouse moved but that picture wasn't scrolled zoomed out in (all supported in my application) and base the redrawing on this facts, and then how do redraw the invalidated region only. BTW Any useful resource on that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Boris: Have you gathered profiling data indicating, that your approach is too slow? You should also learn about the standard way a Windows application performs its painting, and more generally, about the event-based nature of the system.

Comment: @Boris, IInspectable is right - it may seem wasteful to redraw the whole thing every time, and it is, but it's unlikely to matter. Modern processors are so amazingly fast! This is all assuming that the ruler is the only thing you're redrawing, but that should be pretty simple to ensure based on the clipping rectangle. I'm unaware of any resources describing the process.